# Geopoint saving into wrong direction in prase

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation

My Geopoint script is saving into a new group which it is calling "position" in Geopoint.

What i want it to do is saving it into User and set it at column "location" of the user of the app.

I do also have CLLocation.

Here is my script.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground {

            (geoPoint: PFGeoPoint?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {

        PFUser.currentUser()!.setValue(geoPoint, forKey: "location")
        PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()
        }
    }
```

At line:

```
PFUser.currentUser()!.setValue(geoPoint, forKey: "location")
```

I am getting an error saying

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

I am very new to swift and xcode so please let me know if i need to provide more information

Comment: What you need is to have error:NSError then you should have if error == nil {}

Comment: When i do that it just want me to seperate it with a ","

Comment: It says "Expected "," seperator"

Comment: And when i set ":" the if error = nil says "NSEError can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed

Comment: Try this error:NSError?

Comment: "Expected ',' seperator"

Comment: Can you update your code

Comment: I said error : NSError not error.NSError

Comment: Oh my bad. When i replaced error.NSError with error : NSError it i got 2 errors. one at PFGeoPoint line and one at if error == nil. The 1. saying "cannot convert value of type (PPFGeoPoint=, NSError) -> void to expect argument type PFGeoPointResultblock?      and the orher one saying NSError can never be nil

Comment: Did you had the ? Optional sign to NSError

Comment: I actually overlooked that... Now it worked. But  my location is getting saved in parse. Might be since i dont have a location set?

Comment: Can i ask you, what does forkey mean? is that the direction in parse?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am really thankful! I updated the question. Now i get an error. @Lamar